# Country wise user restriction

Tags: java, scala, playframework, location, ip-address

i have to restrict access of my site from some specific countries.i have the ip address of the user. but how i restrict it? should it is compulsory to use a API that provide me its country?`i am making my website in scala 2.1 with play framework 2.2`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any Play plugins out there that do this, as this is a pretty rare use-case. You could use a web based API. This is just one that's out there: http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php

A simple google search will turn up plenty more if that doesn't fit your needs. Keep in mind that these can only be so accurate, and often can be bypassed with proxies. Many of these services can detect proxies, but they don't come free.

The implementation is up to you though. A simple solution would be to create a new `Action` that calls the API and decides what to do with the response, and you would use that Action with every controller function. This isn't a particularly great strategy, however, because all requests will be waiting on the API, so you'd also have to implement some sort of ip white list/black list.

Overall, you're looking at a decent amount of work to accomplish this.

Comment: I would recommend using a Filter instead of an Action. That way, no need to compose the 'GeolocRestricAction' with all the other actions.